# can not access user data in hooks - code iginitor

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

This is my hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                            'class'    => 'UpdateSession',
                            'function' => 'index',
                            'filename' => 'UpdateSession.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks',
                            'params'   => array()
                            );
```

And this is my UpdateSession.php which is placed in hooks folder.

```
<?php

class UpdateSession extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library("session");
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id')) 
    {
        $query =  $this->CI->db->get_where('cp_sessions', array('user_id' => $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id')));
        $session_info = $query->row_array();

        if($session_info['session_id'] !=    $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'))
        {
            $new_session_id = array('session_id' => $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update('cp_sessions', $new_session_id, array('user_id' => $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id')));
        }
    }
}
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\website\pokeradda\application\hooks\UpdateSession.php on line 8
```

I have tried to remove extends `CI_Controller` but same problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pre-controller hook means you are calling your class before controllers are loaded. so that You can not get the CI instance in this hook, because CI is not loaded yet!

> you can’t get the CI instance in SOME hooks :
>
> - CAN’T : pre_system , pre_controller
> - CAN   : post_controller_constructor, post_controller, display_override, cache_override, post_system

you can use My_controller and extend your controller from it. add the functionality in My_controller constructor. (a suggestion as a work-around)